# jq - json list of dicts to csv

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, jq

Input JSON example:

```
[
  {"name":"Θεμιστοκλής","surname":"Παπαϊωάννου","gender":"male","region":"Greece"}, 
  {"name":"Casian","surname":"Cusin","gender":"male","region":"Romania"}
]
```

Now with my code I have output as strings:

```
$ curl -s https://uinames.com/api/?amount=3 | jq '.[] | [.name, .surname] | @csv'
"\"Anamaria\",\"Tămaș\""
"\"Aurora\",\"Coronado\""
"\"Εύηνος\",\"Ελευθερόπουλος\""
```

What I need:

```
"Anamaria","Tămaș"
"Aurora","Coronado"
"Εύηνος","Ελευθερόπουλος"
```

Can anybody explain please what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the -r command-line option when invoking jq.

Example:

```
$ curl -Ss 'https://uinames.com/api/?amount=3' |
   jq -r '.[] | [.name, .surname] | @csv' 
"Γόργασος","Θεοδωρίδης"
"Marta","Brediceanu"
"Iulian","Bârcă"
```